# Extend a subscription automatically or manually?

Tags: user-behavior, psychology

We offer different type of annual subscriptions.
At this time, we inform the customer 2 months before his subscriptions will end, that we are going to extend his subscriptions automatically. If he don't want the subscription anymore, he need to resign from it.

Renew the subscription manually:
`+` The customer won't forget to resign from it and won't be booked for a new year
`-` If he forget to renew the subscription, he will get a penalty (we're a railway company. So then he drive with a expired subscription)

Renew the subscription automatically:
`+` The customer don't need to do anything for the new subscription
`-` If he forgets to resign from it, he will be booked for a whole new year

We think it is easier for the user, so he don't need to care every year to renew his subscription.

But are we thinking in the customers thoughts? Or would it be better to let him choose if he want to renew his subscription manually?

BTW: Our customers are usually using our subscriptions multiple years.
And no, there is no possiblity to renew it monthly (I'm not in the position to decide this)

Comment: When they signed up, were they clearly informed they were signing up to an automatic subscription? Were they given the option?

Comment: @DarrylGodden: At this time, it's not an option, you can't choose. And because of the administation, we can't let the users do that... (sadly). When the sign up, they get inform that the subscription will extend automatically. But do you know after a year that they said that?

Comment: Often my credit card is renewed or changed within a year and so all of these pre-signups are useless anyway. When forced to 'subscribe' usually the first thing I do is unsubscribe. If not immediately, I do it before the year passes. Pointless irritation.

Comment: @nocomprende I don't know what country you're in but where I live this is not common at all... But def something OP should find out about his target group.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 for things that happen monthly which I definitely want to keep paying (electricity, cable internet etc) the "autopay" method deducts directly from my checking account, so that would be different from using a credit card, where "repudiation" is an important feature. Something vital that deducts only every year is... very odd. If it is so important, it must be costly, and so I would probably want to pay each month, and the company would want to cut me off if I don't pay each month. What is important but inexpensive? Can't think of anything at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a good idea to consider easy ways of correcting mistakes in this case. This is a concept taken from the book [Nudge: Improving Decisions about Health, Wealth, and Happiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_%28book%29)

**Make it easy on the users by auto renewing their subscriptions, but also make it easy to cancel subscriptions at any time with no/minimal penalty.**

The example from the book is on enrolling in health insurance.

They notify user they have a pending renewal on their health plan.
If users take no action, auto renewal will happen.
There were un-intentional renewals? Allow users to stop subscription at any time. Un-used portions will be refunded.

Of course this take work to setup, especially dealing with the refunds. However, this approach provides better health care for the users so they wouldn't forget to enrol. People now also have the option to cancel at any time, so they don't have to wonder whether they should enrol or not if they're consider to move sometime that year. That peace of mind makes a huge difference on compliance.

Comment: Healthcare is an interesting example. I pay monthly, so if I do not pay for some reason, I am dropped, the year has nothing to do with it. Also, I want to keep healthcare until I decide to drop it, I certainly don't want it stopping without my consent. So, this is quite different from the usual "pay to get service for a year" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Communicating that a subscription is a trial or a test, and then ask for creditcard or payment possibilities. And autorenew by default and is bad UX - and a dark pattern. alot do this because people forget to cancel it. and thus creating more revenue. its still bad UX - (UX is not conversion rate optimization!)

First you have to figure out, if your subscription service is "NEED to HAVE" and "NICE to HAVE".

NEED to HAVE subscriptions is subscriptions you need in your life: phone, internet, health insurance and so on... "NEED" (health insurance is a really poor example to use as a generic subscription. because it is so vital and so far from things like linkedin-premium and other online services that most UX'ers are faced with)

NICE to HAVE subscriptions is stuff like magazine, online games, xbox gold, netflix, linkedin-premium, small services and in general new concepts that people have not used for years. Things that you are more likely to want to try out before you deciding. things that does not hurt if they run out.

the biggest difference between these to concepts is that one of them needs convincing and testing.

need to have subscriptions is good UX if they are autorenew by default. end of that story - but this is a dark pattern for other subscriptions and not good ux.

nice to have subscriptions can have a trial periode with a free or reduced entry fee. to let people test the concept if they are hard to sell. you often cannot tell if the subscription is valuable to you or not unless you are able to test it.

so if you are introducing a trial periode you should NOT use autorenew the first time. or require creditcard information! - at the end of the first periode you should warn that your trial is running out and that you need to signup to make the subscription autorenewable. ofc. make it easy and warn a few time. no more than two if you ask me.

there are also nice to have subscriptions that are somewhere in between need to have and nice to have - concepts that people are used to and does not require "trial" or too much selling.. concepts like netflix and world of warcraft that has been running for years - these does not hurt to have as autoreneable by default BUT - then you cannot and should not use the word trail or communicate that the first month is a test.

making people sign up for something they manually have to take action on every time is something completely differend and in general has nothing to do with the word subscription...

Answer (score 0):

If the user is signed up for one year automatically as soon as they sign up, without any option - for signing up then I think this needs to be stated explicitly at sign-up time:

> Signing up to our service will subscribe you for one year and your subscription will be automatically renewed each year, unless you cancel.
>
> Please note: you cannot cancel in the first year.

Comment: Because it is a expensive product, you can't just sing up online. So you are going to get a whole bunch of paper work with all the rules in it. But my thought is if you have it in mind after a year.

Comment: Then it's not a UX question.

Comment: UX is not online online. UX is about much more than online stuff.

Comment: Really? I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is like this: If the user wants everything to stay the same (meaning he/she wants to stay subscribed), he/she shouldn't need to do anything.

So automatically extending the subscription should be fine, if the user is properly informed about it.

I think most big rail companies (and other subscription-based companies like internet providers, etc.) are doing it that way, so the users will most likely expect it to be extended automatically.